# How to go to the specified breakpoint in MyEclipse？

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, myeclipse

In my web project controller I have two breakpoint called breakpointA,breakpointB .When I debug the project,if now the code is running in
breakpointB,How can I return to the breakpointA? In visual studio I can drag the  breakpointB to  breakpointA easily.But in MyEclipse how to do that?Do it has shortcut keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do that but the eclipse debug perspective has a "[drop to frame](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-droptoframe.htm)" capability which will take you back to the start of the method. This is standard eclipse functionality, not specific to MyEclipse.